# How can I upload images to an Amazon S3 bucket using Next.js 13's app router and overcome API route structure changes?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js13, app-router

How to upload images to amazon s3 bucket on nextjs13 using app router?

I tried using formidable and multer but both soltions are not working as nextjs changes their api routes structure:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import multer from "multer";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.REGION as string,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY as string,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY as string,
  },
});

async function uploadImageToS3(
  file: Buffer,
  fileName: string
): Promise<string> {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME as string,
    Key: `${Date.now()}-${fileName}`,
    Body: file,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg", // Change the content type accordingly
  };

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
  await s3Client.send(command);

  return fileName;
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    // How to pass the buffer and store the image on s3 bucket ???

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    NextResponse.json({ message: "Error uploading image" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally after much trying, here is the solution:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import sharp from "sharp";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.REGION as string,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY as string,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY as string,
  },
});

async function uploadImageToS3(
  file: Buffer,
  fileName: string
): Promise<string> {
  const resizedImageBuffer = await sharp(file)
    .resize(400, 500) // Specify your desired width or height for resizing
    .toBuffer();

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME as string,
    Key: `${Date.now()}-${fileName}`,
    Body: resizedImageBuffer,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg", // Change the content type accordingly
  };

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
  await s3Client.send(command);

  return fileName;
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const file = formData.get("file") as Blob | null;
    if (!file) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "File blob is required." },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const mimeType = file.type;
    const fileExtension = mimeType.split("/")[1];

    const buffer = Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer());
    const fileName = await uploadImageToS3(
      buffer,
      uuid() + "." + fileExtension
    );

    return NextResponse.json({ success: true, fileName });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    NextResponse.json({ message: "Error uploading image" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, for anyone looking for the full component + route solution [i will leave this gist](https://gist.github.com/carl0zen/7678f16cfeb384b44ba0e64d7bb31965) , based on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify code. Hope this helpful for you.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { createReadStream } from "fs";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.REGION as string,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY as string,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY as string,
  },
});

async function uploadImageToS3(
  fileStream: NodeJS.ReadableStream,
  fileName: string
): Promise<string> {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME as string,
    Key: `${Date.now()}-${fileName}`,
    Body: fileStream,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
  };

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
  await s3Client.send(command);

  return fileName;
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const { file } = request.files; // Assuming the file input name is 'file'
    const { path, name } = file;

    const fileStream = createReadStream(path);
    const uploadedFileName = await uploadImageToS3(fileStream, name);

    response.json({ fileName: uploadedFileName });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    response.json({ message: "Error uploading image" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'NextRequest', anyway thanks for trying